# Is chmod +x ./expand_lapw correct ?

Tags: chmod

I'm new user of Ubuntu.

I have used redhat, however I wrote :

```
chmod +x ./expand_lapw
```

But there is nothing happen. Please let me know ?

Comment: What do you expect? If the command is correct you won't get any feedback from the command. You can test if the flag is set with `ls -al expand_lapw`. Look for the additional `x` at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

`chmod` just applies a different permission mask to a file. In this case, it just marks something as executable (assuming you have write permissions on it and it's a filesystem that supports exec).

It doesn't *do* anything other than that. If you want to execute it, you'd then run:

```
./expand_lapw
```